# Tips for converting an Arduino 'AF_Wave' project to 'waveHC' for a beginner?

Tags: arduino

Is there a step-by-step list of what needs to be changed in order to convert an Arduino sketch using the (old, unsupported) `AF_Wave` library to using `waveHC` (new and shiny)?

(I've searched all around for this, but I can't seem to find it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question..

Excellent tutorial:
http://www.ladyada.net/make/waveshield/libraryhcplay6.html

Comment: Don't forget to tick your own answers - it marks them as 'answered' so they are not shown in the unanswered lists.